# How to make T4 text template have color reserved words?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4

How to make T4 text template have color words like programming c#?

Answer (score 6):

Syntax highlighting for T4 templates is not supported out of the box in VS 2010 but you can download some extension which will add that feature. Simply open your visual studio and go to tools > extension manager. Select Online Gallery and in the search box type T4. It will filter results and you will immediately see several extensions which offers highlighting and intellisense. You can install them and test them to find which one is the best for you. Be aware that some extension can be commercial products but they usually have some trial period or free version.